# Deep copying a tf.function-decorated function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Some code I'm using is trying but failing to `copy.deepcopy` a `@tf.function`-decorated function (as part of pickling). Is there a correct way to do this?

**Simplified reproduction**

Define any simple `@tf.function`-decorated function:

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> @tf.function
... def foo(x): return x * 2
>>> foo
<tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function object at 0x7fc98bec0950>
```

Deepcopying it *before* initialisation works fine:

```py
>>> import copy
>>> copy.deepcopy(foo)
<tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function object at 0x7fc98bec8b50>
```

However, it fails after initialisation:

```py
>>> foo(tf.constant([3.]))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([6.], dtype=float32)>
>>> copy.deepcopy(foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  ....
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

**Comments**

1. I don't mind if the copied version is uninitialized and so has to be recompiled on first use, but I don't want to have to recompile the original function every time I copy it.
2. The `tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.Function` class has a `__getstate__` method that omits the `_lock` attribute and other "unpickleable objects". However, while this might permit shallow copies it doesn't handle deep ones, since the class objects also contain attributes of the following types, which themselves contain locks somewhere inside them:

```py
_stateful_fn: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.function.Function'>
_stateless_fn: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.function.Function'>
_lifted_initializer_graph: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.func_graph.FuncGraph'>
_graph_deleter: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function.FunctionDeleter'>
_concrete_stateful_fn: <class 'tensorflow.python.eager.function.ConcreteFunction'>
```

**Environment**

Tested in Python 3.7.13 on Ubuntu with both TF 2.8 and TF 2.4.

Comment: Maybe you can try doing tf.keras.backend.clear_session() before pickling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out one possible solution just after posting.

Putting the function inside a class seems to let it be copied:

```py
>>> class Foo:
...    @tf.function
...    def __call__(self, x): return x * 2
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo(tf.constant([3.]))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([6.], dtype=float32)>
>>> foo_copy = copy.deepcopy(foo)
>>> foo_copy(tf.constant([3.]))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([6.], dtype=float32)>
```

Interestingy, the copied function does indeed seem to be uninitialised (but that's ok for me).

```py
>>> foo.__call__._get_tracing_count()
1
>>> copy.deepcopy(foo).__call__._get_tracing_count()
0
```